# Injecting & Configuring Gradle Builds

Tags: java, groovy, build, gradle

I'm reading up on Gradle and am very interested in it, specifically because (it *appears*) that it allows the introduction of inheritance into the build process. For instance, if I have a Java web app that might be packaged and deployed to Google App Engine instances as well as Amazon EC2 instances, I need a sophisticated build that can take the same Java, XML, PROPERTIES, CSS and image files and package/deploy them into 2 *drastically*-differently packaged `WAR` files.

GAE apps are very specific as to how they are packaged; EC2 (pretty much) just require that you conform to servlet specs. GAE apps get "deployed" by running an `update` command from the `appcfg.sh` script that comes with your SDK; EC2 has their own way to deploy apps. The point is, they are very different packaging/deployment processes for both PaaS providers:

```
public abstract class PackageTask {
    // ...
}

// Package my Eclipse project for deployment to GAE.
public class AppEnginePackageTask extends PackageTask {
    // ...
}

// Package my Eclipse project for deployment to EC2 instances.
public class AmazonPackageTask extends PackageTask {
    // ...
}

public abstract class DeployTask {
    // ...
}

// Deployment to GAE.
public class AppEngineDeployTask extends DeployTask {
    // ...
}

// Deployment to EC2.
public class AmazonDeployTask extends DeployTask {
    // ...
}
```

Then, I might have a `myapp.gradle` buildfile that templates the build order of tasks:

```
clean()
compile()
package()
deploy()
```

...and somehow, I can configure/inject `AppEnginePackageTask`/`AppEngineDeployTask` in place of `package()`/`deploy()` for a GAE-based build, or I can configure/inject `AmazonPackageTask`/`AmazoneDeployTask` into those templated tasks. Again, I'm not sure how to do this (or even if Gradle *can* do this), but it's what I'm after.

My *understanding* was that Gradle can do this.  Ant can also be forced to have highly-modular, elegant builds that work this way, but being XML-based, it takes some finessing, whereas an OOP-based language like Groovy makes this cleaner and simpler.

However, all the examples I see of Gradle tasks take the following form:

```
task package(dependsOn: 'compile') {
    // ...
}

task deploy(dependsOn: 'package') {
    // ...
}
```

So I ask: these look/feel like non-OOP task definitions. Is my understanding of Gradle (and its OOP nature) fundamentally incorrect? What am I missing here? How can I accomplish these notions of "configurable/injectable build templates" and inheritance-based tasks? Thanks in advance!

**Edit** I re-tagged this question with "`groovy`" because Gradle buildscripts are written in a Groovy DSL, and someone who happens to be a Groovy-guru (say that 5 times fast) might also be able to chime in even if they know little about Gradle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [described here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html), there are *simple* tasks and *enhanced* tasks. The latter are much more flexible and powerful.

The following example isn't exactly what you describe, re:injection, but it illustrates OOP.

Here is the sample build.gradle file. It avoids "package" as that is a keyword in Java/Groovy. The 'build' target depends on 'compile' and some flavour of 'doPack', depending on a property called 'pkgTarget'.

```
task compile << { 
    println "compiling..." 
}

task build() << {
}

build.dependsOn { 
    compile
}

build.dependsOn { 

    if (pkgTarget == "Amazon") {
        task doPack(type: AmazonPackageTask)
    } else if (pkgTarget == "Google") {
        task doPack(type: GooglePackageTask)
    } else {
        task doPack(type: MyPackageTask) 
    }
}
```

where the tasks are defined later in the same file. (Per doc, this code can go into a "build src" directory):

```
// ----- 

class MyPackageTask extends DefaultTask {
    def init() { println 'common stuff' }
    @TaskAction
    def doPackage() {
        println 'hello from MyPackageTask'
    }
}

class AmazonPackageTask extends MyPackageTask {
    @TaskAction
    def doPackage() {
        init()
        println 'hello from AmazonPackageTask'
    }
}

class GooglePackageTask extends MyPackageTask {
    @TaskAction
    def doPackage() {
        init()
        println 'hello from GooglePackageTask'
    }
}
```

and here is the gradle.properties file:

```
pkgTarget=Amazon
```